# Header location redirect makes PHP command execute twice

Tags: php

I have a script that processes payments from a payment provider, and then uses a `PHP` redirect to show a "thank you" page.

Source: (Websend.php include source is here: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=TmmysJiD)

```
include_once 'Websend.php';
if ($file != "GREAT") {
    header("Location: ../failed.html");
    exit();
} else {
    $ws = new Websend("192.168.56.105");
    $ws->connect("passwd");
    $ws->doCommandAsConsole("give " . $token . " 2000");
    $ws->disconnect();
    header('Location: ../success.html');
    exit();
}
```

Source of success.html

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://site.com/index.html"> 
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Some alert");
</script>
```

However `header("Location: ../success.html");` is causing the command to run twice (and give the user the amount twice, which should not happen.
When I remove `header("Location: ../success.html");` the code works as it should be.

Why does this happen?

Comment: is that code on `succes.html` ?? if so the answer should be self evident

Comment: Please post the contents of `succes.html`

Comment: @Dagon No, this is on the PHP file that the payment provider redirects to.

Comment: then that's just weird! p.s you would look a little more 'professional' if you spelt success correctly.

Comment: Pretty sure you can't use relative URLs with `Location`, you should use absolute paths: `header('Location: http://yourwebsite.com/failed.html');`.

Comment: @Dagon I'm sorry haha, the file is actually called `betaling_ontvangen.html` but since this is Dutch I changed it before posting!

Comment: add `exit();` after the header line, in case there is something else on the page. "betaling_ontvangen" sounds painful :-)

Comment: @Dagon Added `exit();` as well, however, still the same.

Comment: So I tried renaming my HTML files to PHP and use a redirect there as well and it will still not work, the only way for it not to get duplicated is by removing the header location, Is there another way to achieve the same thing?

Comment: There's no logical reason that the redirect causes the duplication, that should only happen, if, where you are redirected to runs the code. That's as far as i can help, good luck :-)

Comment: @Dagon That's exactly what my thoughts are right now, I changed the HTML page to a PHP page with a simple message and it seems to work now for some strange reason I still don't understand. Thanks anyway :)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is refreshing success.html

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://site.com/index.html">
```

**EDITED**

have you tried removing `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://site.com/index.html">`? Also try changing `header('Location: ../success.html');` to `header('Location: ../index.html');`

Comment: yup, why is that in there at all

Comment: It's like the following: "User Pays --> Payment provider redirects to checkpayment.php --> checkpayment checks if it is really paid or not then --> redirects to success or fail html --> this file displays an HTML alert and then redirects to the homepage.

Comment: @Vector no, the PHP code is on a different file, "check_payment.php"

Comment: have you tried removing `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://site.com/index.html">`? Also try changing `header('Location: ../success.html');` to `header('Location: ../index.html');` just for testing

Comment: @Vector I tried this and It seems like this works better! Thank you very much I think for some reason the HTML/PHP combination is getting a bit weird, maybe it was a server-related issue I'm still unsure, could you change your answer here above so I can mark it as an answer :)?